# How to modify html title separator in Sphinx doc generator

Tags: python, html, documentation, python-sphinx

By default it seems to what to use a long dash '--' as the separator between page title and overall site html_title that's set in the config.py file.

We'd like to change this to a '|' character instead.

I can add a block to the layout.html template to modify the title I'm just unsure of what to actually write for that. I want it to be 'page_title | html_title' in the title tags across the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The em dash (`&#8212;`) comes from the [layout.html](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/sphinx/themes/basic/layout.html) template:

```
{%- if not embedded and docstitle %}
{%- set titlesuffix = " &#8212; "|safe + docstitle|e %}
{%- else %}
{%- set titlesuffix = "" %}
{%- endif %}
```

The value of `titlesuffix` is used a bit further down in the template:

```
{%- block htmltitle %}
<title>{{ title|striptags|e }}{{ titlesuffix }}</title>
{%- endblock %}
```

To customize:

1. Ensure that you have `templates_path = ['_templates']` in conf.py.
2. Create a file called layout.html in the _templates directory.
3. In layout.html, add the following:

   ```
   {% extends "!layout.html" %}

   {%- set customtitlesuffix = " | "|safe + docstitle|e %}

   {%- block htmltitle %}
   <title>{{ title|striptags|e }}{{ customtitlesuffix }}</title>
   {%- endblock %}
   ```

See also https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/templating.html.